# Babel / Node / Relay / Webpack cache?

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs, graphql, relay

#### Generally:

Do these four systems have caches? And if so, what is the method for clearing each?

#### Specifically:

Having trouble with a react app we are developing. Seemingly sporadically we get the following error when developing locally:

> "Invariant Violation: RelayQL: Unexpected invocation at runtime. Either the Babel transform was not set up, or it failed to identify this call site. Make sure it is being used verbatim as `Relay.QL`."

Am yet to notice any particular reason why/when this starts happening.

I finally found a hack solution which involved me going into the referenced component file referenced (further in the error msg, unshown) and deleting the RelayQL fragment inside e.g.

```
export default Relay.createContainer(PinterestShare, {
    fragments: {
        resource: () => Relay.QL`
        fragment on Resource {
            id
            title
            files {
                type
                images {
                    medium { url width }
                }
            }
        }
        `
    }
});
```

to

```
export default Relay.createContainer(PinterestShare, {
    fragments: {
        resource: () => Relay.QL`
        `
    }
});
```

I then save, and reboot the app. It crashes, obviously, as the fragment is malformed. So I undo the change back to the original, and reboot the app again. Now, the original error is fixed, despite no code actually changing.

So what happened? Somehow doing this process is flushing some cache? Is this in node, webpack, relay, or babel? I've tried rebooting my machine inbetween, as well as `killall node`, neither which work, which implies to me it is not RAM based...

The annoying part now is I am having to do this for all of my individual component files. Surely there must be a way to purge this mystery cache enmass for the whole app?

Comment: I think I've ran into this error in the past when updating the GraphQL schema on the server. Does this happen after you modify the server code? If so you'll need to regenerate your `schema.json` file and restart your client packager, every time you make changes. Are you using `webpack`? It has a `cacheDirectory`, but I think you would have had to explicitly set it to true.

Comment: Yes- using webpack. We regenerate the schema.json in our run script, but I've also tried manually deleting and rebuilding the schema, neither which help. Webpack cacheDirectory could be a good lead though... let me check that out, i'll also update my question- as you're right- webpack could likely be the suspect here

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: no so the bug never reappeared before we shipped the app, so never resolved, but next step would have been looking at webpack cache https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cache, perhaps flushing it by running with cache false, then back to cache true...